# `Good/correct English' for a 'pay back the effort'

Tags: expressions, british-english

I'm looking for a term/expression/word that is less plumb then

> Introducing the following concept is difficult but will **pay back** in the end.

Comment: less ...... than

Comment: Unless you are writing a guide for teachers, "Introducing the following concept is difficult" is a big part of the awkwardness of this sentence. Even if you are writing for an audience who will be doing the "introducing" themselves, a clarifying prepositional phrase would help, such as "Introducing the following concept to your students..."

Comment: What do you mean by *plumb*?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**"rewarding approach"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22rewarding%20approach%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22rewarding%20approach%22&tbm=bks&start=10)

shows many examples at Google Books

> Strength and Conditioning for Young Athletes: Science and ... - Page
>   44 Rhodri S. Lloyd, ‎Jon L. Oliver - 2013 - ‎Preview - ‎More editions
>
> A multidisciplinary approach that considers physiological,
>   psychological and sociological contributors to developing talent **may
>   be the most difficult but most** **rewarding approach**.

Answer (score 2):

I proffer-

> Introducing the following concept is difficult but ***rewards/benefits will follow***
>   in the end.

Answer (score 0):

- **it will compensate**
- **it will be gratifying**
- **it will be profitable**

> - compensate (vb) "to provide something good as a balance against something bad or undesirable" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compensate)
> - gratifying (adj)  "giving pleasure or satisfaction" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gratifying)
> - profitable (adj) "producing good or helpful results or effects" [TFD](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/profitable)